# first time building Hyper V hardware requirements

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hypervisor

I intend to build a white-box that will be running a host server 2008 with hyper V and have the guest VMs on a separate  SSD drive.

1. Is it better (in terms of  to run the the 2008 server host on an IDE drive as opposite to SSD?
2. Considering this is a white box for lab use is there a significant performance gain if I use a raid controller card with raid 0 setup and two SSD drives as oppose to connect the internal SSD directly to the motherboard (GA-Z77MX-D3H) to host the guested VMs?

Comment: why not windows 2012?

Comment: good question. 2012 hyper-v host is free (so no licensing costs) and a LOT better.

Answer (score 1):

1: should not make a difference. Just do not run mutliple vm's from one HD. HD's break down IO wise, SSD have tons of reserve.

2: Yes, but not that much. Raid 0 best doubles your IO - the SSD themselves have plenty of IOPS budget.

I would be more concerned about memory etc. - with SSD based storage you already are out of "problem" territory.

Comment: As comment to 2: an SSD is about 100+ times faster than a HD - so doubling that is not really making that much a difference.